# Storing Math.Numerics.Fit.Line data into two separate variables simultaneously

Tags: c#, mathnet-numerics

I am working on a excercise here which is gathering data from a file and then displaying it on graph.

I am using a linkedIn video to help me here but I stumped on how they are able to store this extension method into two separate variables at the same time.

```
var (intersect,slope) = MathNet.Numerics.Fit.Line(arrx.ToArray(), arry.ToArray());
```

If I keep one variable on the left side the red lines go away but if I keep both "intersect" and "slope", it gives me an error.

Comment: What version of Visual Studio and C# are you running?

Comment: I think it's a reference/package issue as it works fine for me in a new project.

Comment: https://gunnarpeipman.com/select-csharp-version/

Comment: @mjwills just seen your msg after. It says "Automatically selected based on framework version"

Comment: Yep - so compare your two projects. I suspect they are different framework versions.

Comment: @mjwills  Thanks for your help. I finally got it to work by changing it to the 4.7 .Net Framework